# Show datailed differences for two csv files with bash or awk

Tags: bash, csv, difference

I need your advice about a situation I have comparing two cvs files in bash:

file1.csv

```
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000043.000|15|0|49300|1|42|4
300315830|300315830|300000419|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000004020.000|18|0|31583000|89|43|4
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|10|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000210.000|14|0|49300|1|43|4
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|16|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000014.000|16|0|49300|89|42|4
300146897|300146897|300000394|300000000|609|1|12619|0|0|+000000000000020.000|1|0|14689700|7|36|4
```

file2.csv

```
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000053.000|1|0|49300|1|42|4
300315830|300315830|300000419|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000004020.000|18|0|49300|89|43|4
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|10|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000219.000|14|0|49300|1|43|5
```

The `diff -y file1.csv file2.csv` command shows a similar output I'm looking for:

```
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000043.000|15|0|49300|1|42|4       |    300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000053.000|1|0|49300|1|42|4
300315830|300315830|300000419|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000004020.000|18|0|31583000|89|43|4   |    300315830|300315830|300000419|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000004020.000|18|0|49300|89|43|4
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|10|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000210.000|14|0|49300|1|43|4      |    300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|10|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000219.000|14|0|49300|1|43|5
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|16|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000014.000|16|0|49300|89|42|4     <
300146897|300146897|300000394|300000000|609|1|12619|0|0|+000000000000020.000|1|0|14689700|7|36|4   <
```

However I'm trying to get a more advanced output identifying with an asterik `*` the differences between cells and if a whole row does not exists in one of the sides, then put a dash `-`. And finally create one output file per side (because after that I'm going to convert each output csv to html in order to embbed them in a html file), something like:

file1.out.csv

```
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000043.000*|15|0|49300|1|42|4
300315830|300315830|300000419|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000004020.000|18|0|31583000*|89|43|4
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|10|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000210.000*|14|0|49300|1|43|4*
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|16|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000014.000|16|0|49300|89|42|4
300146897|300146897|300000394|300000000|609|1|12619|0|0|+000000000000020.000|1|0|14689700|7|36|4
```

file2.out.csv

```
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000053.000*|1|0|49300|1|42|4
300315830|300315830|300000419|300000000|2|0|12619|0|0|+000000000004020.000|18|0|49300*|89|43|4
300000493|300000323|300000323|300000000|10|0|12619|0|0|+000000000000219.000*|14|0|49300|1|43|5*
-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-
-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-
```

Hopefully you can help me here.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look at other tools like `meld` or `tkdiff`

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution will be use:

```
paste -d '\n' file1.csv file2.csv > pasted.csv
```

And then read the output file to generate I need